# Who gets to know first when a new file is added on device? (Android)

Tags: android, file, filesystemwatcher

Which component is notified first when a new file is added on the device.
The new file can be added in any of the way (1. File operations on device 2. Via Bluetooth 3. WiFi 4.Internet downloads etc)
Is there any broadcast that we can register for or thru some framework code?

FileObserver is not serving the purpose! I cannot know if some file/folder is added by the user after one level of the root (/mnt/sdcard/) folder

Answer (score 1):

Use [FileObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html).

Comment: Thanks for that Yuku! So now if I use FileObserver for **/mnt/sdcard/** , I can get to know any change that will be made in any of the files on my device right!?

Comment: I have used the FileObserver on the root folder but couldn't get to know the events that happened in the internal folders..! If root has Folder A which in turn has Folders B&C.. I'm not able to get any info if something happens inside Folder B or Folder C